# What is bookmark blasting?

Tags: seo

I've heard this term from a commentary about SEO but I don't believe they went into an explanation of what exactly it was. It sounds like an interesting concept - would anyone here be familiar with what it is?

Comment: +1 nice question, there are few resources that explain this concept clearly online

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bookmark blasting is a variation of [backlinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlink) which utilizes social bookmarking sites to market content. It serves three main purposes:

**1. Search Engine Indexing**

By placing content on these actively indexed social bookmarking websites, it allows the link itself to be indexed, aiding search engine optimization.

**2. Rank Accumulation**

With the popularity of these social aggregators, multiple clicks via the backlink aids in incrementing the rank of your content.

**3. Marketability**

In general, posting your content on social bookmarking sites allows real users to engage and experience your material first-hand, allowing you to market your product in an effective manner.